# Problems with an execute command

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have this command but I need to add/set a score instead of summoning a sheep:

```
/execute @a[score_talkVill_min=1,score_hold_min=1] ~ ~ ~ summon Sheep
```

Comment: You should just be able to replace the summon command with the scoreboard command that you want. Is there something you've tried and couldn't get to work?

Comment: I was trying with this: /execute @p[score_talkVill_min=1,score_hold_min=1] ~ ~ ~ scoreboard players add @p TalkVillGreen 1

Answer (score 1):

all you need is to replace the summon command with something like this:

```
/scoreboard players add <player> <objective> <amount>
```

that should work, but I can't test it right now, so if it doesn't work, that's probably why

hopefully I helped!